# Cartoon in which a family falls into a whirlpool and reemerges in a magical land

Tags: story-identification, magic, cartoon, isekai

I am looking for a cartoon show from the 80s or 90s in which a family(?) falls into a [whirlpool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whirlpool) and comes out in a magical land.

All of the family members are given items that possess abilities. One of them is given a bow that shoots magical arrows that can change form and even tie people up.

I watched this show in the mid 90s in Germany.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this a series or a movie?

Comment: I have closed your question as a duplicate, because the accepted answer matches another one on the site. You will still receive points for upvotes. This just ties the questions together in the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ***[Dungeons & Dragons](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085011/?ref_=kw_li_tt)*** (1983–1985).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_(TV_series)):

> The show focuses on a group of friends aged between 9 and 15 who are transported to the realm of Dungeons & Dragons by taking a magical dark ride on an amusement park roller coaster. Upon arriving in the realm they meet Dungeon Master (named for the referee in the role-playing game) who gives each child a magical item.

A group of kids go on a rollercoaster ride and are transported to a fantasy world, where they're given magical items, including a bow that fires arrows made of energy. There wasn't an actual whirlpool, but the portal they went through was a swirling blue tunnel.

Comment: That is it! Thank you so much!!